# sql server slow only on LAN

Tags: sql-server, performance, local-area-network

I have a MS SQL Server instance on my server.

Running `select * from sys.columns` takes 00:00 seconds. (just as a sample, most queries have same issue)

When i run the same query in `SSMS`, it takes 30 seconds+. sometimes a few minutes.

What might be of interest: the first approxiamtely 500-600 rows come back immediately, then the rest come back slowly.

This issue only started happening today.

What i've tried:

- I turned off kaspersky on my client pc
- I turned off opendns
- I restarted both pcs
- Turned off most apps conectiong to the db
- I checked activity monitor, nothing major going on there
- Client statistics doesnt either show anything much

Still the issue persists

On the server its consistently 0 seconds, remotely on the lan approx a minute

Moreover, i connected from my client pc via SSMS to remote servers overseas, and it was also 0 seconds

Seems to be only between the pcs here and the server

What can the issue be? Where can I look?

**UPDATE**
2 days ago I had a technician, worked for a while, restarted stuff here and there, and yesterday all worked okay. today the issue is back

I tried disconnecting all client pcs from the database (closed all apps that connect to the db) and running the query again. again its taking circa 35 seconds

**UPDATE 2**

Hi all. I'm experiencing this same issue again. Though now it's even odder, since I'm experiencing this also on a client pc which is a brand new installation of windows 10. No custom firewall/antivirus or anything like that.

What I've tried:

1. I realized that the server's dns address was pointing to OpenDns, since I don't use that anymore I switched the server to 10.0.0.138/8.8.8.8. This didn't help much.
2. I manually added the entries to the servers' Hosts file (i.e 10.0.0.1 MyClient etc). This made a huge difference in SSMS from MyClient to MyServer, but didn't solve the problem all the way. Meaning:

   - Most queries are returning now instantaneously, but not all.
   - `nslookup MyClient` still gives the same error (`google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find MyClient: Non-existent domain`)
   - FWIW ping MyClient return immediately on the server with no issues
   - A .net app using Entity Framework still takes approximately 30 seconds to return the same query that SSMS return in 0 seconds on the same machine

If possible, I wouldnt mind totally disabling the nslookup on SQL Server. I have no need for it. So far though, I couldnt find any such option.

What else can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess (as it could be a variety of things), but it might be reverse DNS lookup of the clients IP is timing out for some reason on the server. Quick test would be to see how long `nslookup <client IP>` takes to resolve or perhaps add the client IP to the servers hosts file entry and test the query.

Comment: Why would the SQL server need to look up the PTR record of the client?

Comment: Well as I say, it is a guess, so something to try.  However it is not uncommon for server side systems to do a PTR lookup - for example for the purposes of logging the hostname of clients and if this process times out you can see a corresponding lag on the initial connection - especially if its 30+ seconds or so, it implies something in the chain is doing a lookup that is timing out.  However, this this is just another thing to try and so rule out, it is quick to test by trying the two approaches I suggest above, I suggest trying both and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hi. I dont think `nslookup` should work locally. In any case, on the server I ran `nslookup station4` (name of client pc) and I got an error after about 30 seconds that resolver1.opnedns.com cant find station4 non existent domain

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively or by default perform reverse DNS lookups. If it did then a reverse lookup zone would be an installation requirement for SQL server, and it isn't.

Comment: True, but 30s to fail to look up a record is definitely another issue that should to be resolved.  And DNS (forward or reverse) can affect all sorts of things (e.g. if you were using Windows Authentication on a domain you would definitely have performance/connectivity issues with poor DNS configuration).  For example if I run `nslookup station4` on my laptop, it returns instantly with `Non-existent domain`, as should be the case on the server here, it should not take 30s.

Comment: Right. I could see some kind of stored procedure being configured to do that, but not natively. It's strange that SSMS would have that delay while executing a query. I think the key thing to do at this point would be to run a process monitor and possibly a network monitor to analyze what's happening.

Comment: Hi. I'm again expreiencing the issue. i tried what @AlexMoore mentioned about the `nslookup` and it is continuosly timing out on the server with "my.firewall cant find machshevet non existent domain". (client to server is okay). so what do i do know? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend sorting out DNS resolution for that server. What server is used for DNS, is there something on the network preventing you from talking to it?